# Rollback qcow image of kvm guest

Tags: kvm, btrfs

Good morning, I have a fedora server, in which I have kvm with virt-manager. The images of the guests are qcow2. Days ago by mistake 2 images of 2 guests were deleted. Both are in the snapshot the day before, but I can't put them back in the location where they were deleted.
The snapshots are made with btrfs, the partition of the vm and the snapshots is the same

---

sorry for the delay in answering. yes, I mean the host. Before any problem, cp /mnt/snapshots/server/serverimage.qcow2 / mnt / vm / server / for example.
At this moment, when doing the example, cp throws the input / output error. Solve by copying with rsync and the --inplace function (at the end of the copy rsync also gave an error and began to copy again, but what was already copied was in its entirety and working.
Now, the cp and rsync errors, are they disk errors? btrfs partition? Do not know.

Comment: "I can't put them back in the location where they were deleted" Can you elaborate? Why is that so? What happens when you try?

Comment: Thanks for answering, my English is not very good. I have a snapshot with qcow2 images of the guests, I want to copy those images to the folder where the images that were deleted were. Try cp, and it gives input / output error. Then with rsync and it says: rsync: read errors mapping "/home/folder/file.ext": Input / output error (5)
WARNING: /home/folder/file.ext failed verification - update discarded (will try again). How can I put those images back and then start with virsh start guest

Comment: Your English is above average in my opinion. However, if you get an I/O error, something is wrong with your filesystem, or what you are trying can't be done on BTRFS.